# What would be the "lo" interface equivalent on windows

Tags: java, windows, unix, network-programming, network-interface

What would be the "lo" interface equivalent when programming on a windows platform.

for instance when i want to use the following line:

```
NetworkInterface interf = NetworkInterface.getByName("lo");
```

or

```
NetworkInterface interf = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth1");
```

what would be its equivalent on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `loopback` or `localhost`, but the answer greatly depends on context. The reason I suggest these names is because they are present in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\networks` and `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` respectively.